# AWS CDK HttpApi, Custom Domain and lambda alias

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am going crazy trying to figure this out. I have a custom domain. I have a python lambda hooked to a REST API. I am trying to have a dev and prod stage on the REST side that points to a specific lambda alias. The lambda function is setup to take the specific stage into account (point to dev tables v. prod tables and so forth).

The code will deploy to one of the stages, but when I go to push to the next stage I get a failure that the domain belongs to another stack. Should I split the REST API into its own stack or can I do it slightly different than I do now?

I have tried splitting them out into their own stacks, but not sure if I need to try and import the HttpApi into the lambda stack or the lambda into the HttpApi stack.

Stack Code (lambda_stack.py):

```
from aws_cdk import CfnOutput, Duration, RemovalPolicy, Stack
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2
from aws_cdk import aws_apigateway as apigw
from aws_cdk import aws_apigatewayv2_alpha as apigwv2
from aws_cdk import aws_certificatemanager as acm
from aws_cdk import aws_dynamodb as ddb
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as _lambda
from aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_integrations_alpha import HttpLambdaIntegration
from constructs import Construct


class MyStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, stg: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        self.stg = stg
        self.func_envs = kwargs.get("func_envs", {})

        function_base_layer = _lambda.LayerVersion(
            self,
            "BaseLayer",
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("layer.zip"),
            compatible_runtimes=[_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
            compatible_architectures=[_lambda.Architecture.X86_64],
            layer_version_name=f"Base_Layer",
        )

        function_vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "lambda_vpc", vpc_id="vpc-123456")

        lambda_func = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            "lambda_func",
            function_name="lambda_func",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda.zip"),
            handler="app.handler",
            layers=[function_base_layer],
            environment=self.func_envs,
            memory_size=512,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(30),
            architecture=_lambda.Architecture.X86_64,
            current_version_options=_lambda.VersionOptions(
                removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
                description=f"{self.stg}-123456",
            ),
            vpc=function_vpc,
        )

        domain_cert = acm.Certificate.from_certificate_arn(
            self,
            "DomainCert",
            "arn:aws:acm:region:123456:certificate/353434343434343",
        )

        _domain = apigwv2.DomainName(
            self,
            "Domain",
            domain_name="api.example.com",
            certificate=domain_cert,
            endpoint_type=apigw.EndpointType.REGIONAL,
            security_policy=apigw.SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2,
        )
        _domain.apply_removal_policy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)

        lambda_func_version = lambda_func.current_version

        lambda_func_alias = _lambda.Alias(
            self,
            "LambdaAlias",
            alias_name=f"local-{lambda_func_version.version}",
            version=lambda_func_version,
        )

        lambda_integration = HttpLambdaIntegration(
            "LambdaIntegration",
            handler=lambda_func_alias,
        )

        http_api = apigwv2.HttpApi(
            self,
            "lambda-http-api",
            api_name="lambda-http-api",
            default_domain_mapping=apigwv2.DomainMappingOptions(
                domain_name=_domain
            ),
        )

        lambda_route = http_api.add_routes(
            path="/{proxy+}",
            methods=[apigwv2.HttpMethod.POST],
            integration=lambda_integration,
        )

        http_api_local_stage = http_api.add_stage(
            id=f"http-api-{self.stg}-stage",
            stage_name=self.stg,
            auto_deploy=True,
            domain_mapping=apigwv2.DomainMappingOptions(domain_name=_domain, mapping_key=self.stg),
        )
        http_api_local_stage.apply_removal_policy(RemovalPolicy.DESTROY)
```

CDK App code (app.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

import aws_cdk as cdk
from constructs import Construct

from test_lambda.lambda_stack import MyStack

env_info: dict = {
    "region": os.environ.get("AWS_REGION", "us-east-1"),
    "account": os.environ.get("AWS_ACCOUNT_ID", "123456789"),
}

app = cdk.App()

MyStack(app, "test-lambda-dev", stg="dev", env=env_info)
MyStack(app, "test-lambda-prod", stg="prod", env=env_info)
```